# Add custom jQuery to form as a module

Tags: 7, javascript

I'd like to get the following jQuery code to run on any forms on my site:

```
(function($) {
  // Hide any N/A radio buttons
  $('.form-radio[value=_none]').parent().hide();

  // Uncheck a radio button on double-click
  $('.form-radio').dblclick(function(){
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

I've read that I can probably just add it to my template.php file, but I'd like to put it in a module. How would I do that?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the suggestions! So I went with option 3 because it seemed to make the most sense to me for my use-case. I still wasn't getting my jQuery to actually work though. I've updated it to this now:

```
(function($){      
  Drupal.behaviors.doubleClickNA = {
    attach: function (context) {
      // Hide the N/A radio button
      $('.form-radio[value=_none]').parent().hide();

      // Enable the double-click unchecker function
      $('.form-radio').dblclick(function(){
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
        $(this).parent().parent().$('.form-radio[value=_none]').prop('checked', true);
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

That seems to get the N/A radio button to disappear, but the second function still doesn't work. The $('document').ready part was the key for the first function (duh, right?), but I believe I need to use a behavior to get the double click action to work after the page as finished rendering. What more am I missing here?

Answer (score 5):

You have different ways/options to add custom javascript/jQuery file with your module.

**Option 1:** Add myscript.js in module info file (mymodule.info).

```
scripts[] = js/myscript.js
```

**Option 2:** Add myscript.js using `hook_init` and `drupal_add_js`

```
function mymodule_init() {
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULE_NAME') .'/js/myscript.js', 'file');
}
```

**Option 3:** Add myscript.js to any Drupal form or any callback that contains Drupal form

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#attached']['js'][] = array(
    'data' => drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULE_NAME') . '/js/myscript.js', 
    'type' => 'file',
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to add it as a script file (eg. mysite.js) in the module directory and add:

```
scripts[] = mysite.js
```

to the .info file for the module. That way it will be aggregated with the other javascript files and will be an active library on all pages.